# django - Can't save model more than once with same user

Tags: python, django

I've created a model storing track info, mp3, png and a slug as well as the username associated with the model.

I can save the model just fine, but when I try to save another one (So that there is two models with the same username), django tells me that "Track with this User already exists!"

I don't want that, I want to be able to save as many models I want with the same user.

Here is my models.py (I have registered it in the admin panel)

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.core.files.images import get_image_dimensions
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.


class Track(models.Model):

    def generate_user_folder_tracks(instance, filename):
        return "uploads/users/%s/tracks/%s.mp3" % (instance.user, instance.slug)

    def is_mp3(self):
        if not self.name.endswith('.mp3'):
            raise ValidationError(u'You may only upload mp3 files for tracks!')

    def generate_user_folder_art(instance, filename):
        return "uploads/users/%s/art/%s.png" % (instance.user, instance.slug)

    def is_square_png(self):
        if not self.name.endswith('.png'):
            raise ValidationError("You may only upload png files for album art!")
        else:
            w, h = get_image_dimensions(self)
            if not h == w:
                raise ValidationError("This picture is not square! Your picture must be equally wide as its height.")
            else:
                if not (h + w) >= 1000:
                    raise ValidationError("This picture is too small! The minimum dimensions are 500 by 500 pixels.")
        return self


    # Variables

    track_type_choices = [
        ('ORG', 'Original'),
        ('RMX', 'Remix'),
        ('CLB', 'Collab'),
        ('LIV', 'Live'),
    ]

    # Model Fields
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)    
    desc = models.TextField(max_length=7500)
    track_type = models.CharField(max_length=3,
                                 choices=track_type_choices,
                                 default='ORG')

    track_type_content = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    created = models.TimeField(auto_now=True,auto_now_add=False)

    upload = models.FileField(upload_to=generate_user_folder_tracks,validators=[is_mp3])
    albumart = models.ImageField(upload_to=generate_user_folder_art,validators=[is_square_png])

    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50)
```

Any idea on what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
```

`unique = true` means every model needs to have a different user.  This is similar to Django's [OneToOne field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField).

Make sure you run

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

and

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Setting the boolean to false raises this error: IntegrityError at /admin/tracks/track/add/
UNIQUE constraint failed: tracks_track.user_id

Comment: You have to make migrations when you change your modal.

Comment: Migrate your database.

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly now. I can't believe I missed something as obvious as migrating.